# Making area/volume calculations that use SIA rigorous

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, topos-theory, synthetic-differential

There are some intriguing "proofs" using Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis of theorems concerning areas and volumes. Some examples:

- A proof that $\sin'(0) = 1$.
- A proof that the surface area of a cone is $\pi r \sqrt{h^2 + r^2} + \pi r^2$
- A proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.
- A proof of the arc-length formula.

These "proofs" can be found in the book *A Primer of Infinitesimal Analysis* by JL Bell. To what extent can these proofs be made rigorous?

Using the surface area of a cone example, we need some way of defining surface area before carrying out the computation.

[edit]

Concerning where the lack of rigour is: The book appears to treat geometric figures as being made up of infinitely many infinitesimal simplices. It calculates the area/volume/length of an infinitesimal simplex, and then uses integration to calculate the area/volume/length of the whole figure. In calculating the area of an infinitesimal simplex, it is assumed that these simplices satisfy classical rules of Euclidean geometry, like Pythagoras's Theorem, $A=\frac12bh$, and so on. No explicit limiting argument is used.

You can find similar calculations in the freely available article [*An Introduction to Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~oconnor/sia.pdf) by M O'Connor.

Comment: What does 'rigorous' mean?  I.e., in what sense are they not already rigorous?  (I haven't read the book, so I don't know about these specific proofs, but my understanding is that SIA already is a rigorous discipline.  In fact, the book's subtitle is "A rigorous, axiomatically formulated presentation of the 'zero-square', or 'nilpotent' infinitesimal.")

Comment: @jkabrg, I think your last sentence answers @LSpice’s comment well. For that reason it would also help to provide Bell’s definition or way of introducing surface area.

Comment: @LSpice See my latest edit

Comment: @MattF. Bell doesn't really provide a definition. The article I linked to uses similar sorts of arguments

Comment: Yeah, those arguments are disappointing if you know the usual calculus. You can say that the arclength $a(x)$ from $0$ to $x$ satisfies $da/dx=\sqrt{1+f’^2}$ or say that $a(x+d)-a(x)=\sqrt{1+f’^2}d$: either will imply the integral formula, but there’s not a huge difference in rigor or intuition between them.

Comment: @MattF. OK, but why can you apply Pythagoras's Theorem to the small triangle? Maybe I'm nitpicking

Comment: This is about arclength in the $xy$-plane as a metric space, so the Euclidean metric is given. Ordinarily, you prove that the integral is the supremum of the lengths of the secant paths. In SIA there is no supremum; you define arclength as a generalization of polygonal perimeter which satisfies additivity conditions. Then applying those conditions at the infinitesimal level gives the differential equation and the integral.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I thought my question was a bit silly. And I thought your answer was wrong too. So it didn't make sense to keep it. Anyway, if you'd prefer it, I'll undelete the question